# Why jQuery animate is not working?

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Jquery </title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            #change_me {
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                left: 400px;
                font: 24px arial;
            }
            #move_up #move_down #color #disappear {
                padding: 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="color">Color me</button>
        <button id="move_down">Move Down</button>
        <button id="move_up">Move Up</button>
        <button id="hide">Hide me</button>
        <div id="change_me">Make me do stuff</div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#color").click(function() {
                    $("#change_me").css("color", "green");
                });
                $("#move_down").click(function() {
                    $(#change_me").animate({top:500},2000);
                });
                $("#move_up").click(function() {
                    $(#change_me").animate({top:30},200);
                });
                $("#hide").click(function() {
                    $("#change_me").toggle("slow");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this code, no one button is not working.

I wrote each line by own, may I know, what is my mistake?

Comment: typo: `$(#change_me")` you missed the opening quote mark

Comment: viva syntax highlighting

Comment: check my answer @sona with demo

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error [**Working Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/1fd2vytL/) missed to add the `"` check the code below.

Working code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#color").click(function() {
        $("#change_me").css("color", "green");
    });
    $("#move_down").click(function() {
        $("#change_me").animate({ top: 500 }, 2000);
    });
    $("#move_up").click(function() {
        $("#change_me").animate({ top: 30 }, 200);
    });
    $("#hide").click(function() {
        $("#change_me").toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector for `$(#change_me")` is false. You forgot to put double quote for those selector. Here your fixed code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#color").click(function() {
    $("#change_me").css("color", "green");
  });
  $("#move_down").click(function() {
    $("#change_me").animate({top:500},2000); // Here you forgot to put "
  });
  $("#move_up").click(function() {
    $("#change_me").animate({top:30},200); // Here you forgot to put "
  });
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    $("#change_me").toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is missing the opening " mark:

```
$(#change_me").animate({top:30},200);
```

it should read:

```
$("#change_me").animate({top:30},200);
```

If this still does not work, can you provide more detail like browser version